# Manifold induced by multivariate function

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, terminology, manifolds

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ with
$$
f(\mathbf{x})=\exp\left(-\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert^2\right)
$$
I am interested in the terminology about the manifold where points $(\mathbf{x}, f(\mathbf{x}))$ lie. First of all, is this a $n$-dimensional manifold? In my understanding, $f$ is differential everywhere. Is this true?

If so, my calculation on the gradient of $f$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$ give
$$
\nabla f(\mathbf{x})=-2\exp\left(-\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert^2\right)\mathbf{x}.
$$
Is this correct?

Finally, for each $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ one can define a vector that corresponds to its gradient. What can be said about this "vector field"? Do the curves that are defined by this vector field have a special name, meaning?

Comment: The terminology you are looking for is the graph of $f$

Comment: Also, the 'derivative' of $f$ is not what you wrote, neither is its differential. The termonology for this is *gradient*.